# Multibranch pipeline per-branch parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a build job on Bamboo that has parameterized branches. All branches (for e.g. feature branches created by developers at will) have a default set of parameters, and specific branches override some of them. Note that once I set a variable for a given branch to a certain value, every build of that branch takes that value. I'm trying to recreate this in Jenkins, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do so.

I created a multibranch pipeline and defined the parameters in my Jenkinsfile with suitable defaults. However, the only way I can override the parameters for a branch is to click "Build with parameters" and update them. That works for that build, but next build that gets triggered reverts back to using the default values. This seems like such a basic use case that I feel like I must be missing something or misconfigured the project somehow, considering I don't have any experience using Jenkins before trying this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Wow, you're lucky... I can't even get 'build with parameters' to appear when I have a multibranch pipeline.  Which... kinda makes the multibranch pipeline useless for me.  I ended up just making a Project-Prod, a Project-Dev, and a Project-Sandbox pipeline, and anyone can force-push features to the sandbox branch to demo our work to our project manager.

Comment: I worked out a decently convenient way to do this. My JenkinsFile defines parameters and their default values (which in our case work for any arbitrary feature branch). For long-living branches like master I override parameter values in the Jenkins UI and my team knows that they're supposed to only do a Rebuild from a build known to have correct values. (Build with Parameters would use the default values which we wouldn't want).

Comment: What do you mean by `Rebuild from a build known to have correct values`? Wouldn't Build with Parameters enable you to override defaults?

Comment: Yes, we ran Build with Parameters with the right parameter values for a branch, and then onwards did Rebuild, which carries over the parameter values. It's not ideal, but my team was small enough to manage.

So for e.g. a parameter called "endpoint" is defaulted to "localhost:8080", and for a long-lived develop branch we run "Build with parameters" with endpoint=server:8080, then we just do Rebuild, which retains the endpoint=server:8080 value.